# Circuitikz - Partway modifiers behave differently in Emacs Preview mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, emacs, auctex, preview

This simplified version of my source code produces different results when simply run through LaTeX and when viewed using Emacs/Auctex Preview mode.  **My question is how to get around this problem with Preview.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\marknode}[2][45]{%
  \node[circle, draw, red, inner sep=1pt, pin={[red,
    font=\tiny]#1:#2}] at (#2.center) {}; }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  % \renewcommand{\marknode}{}
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \def\dx{3} \def\dy{4} \draw (0,0) node[ground,name=gnd] {} (gnd)
    ++(0,\dy) coordinate(a) to[american voltage source,
    l_=$\begin{matrix} & + \\ & V_\textsc{s} \\ & \qty{10}{V} \\ & -
    \end{matrix}$,name=Vs] (gnd)
    (Vslabel) ++(-0.5,0) node[] {$I_\textsc{s} \big\uparrow$}
    ;
    \marknode{a} \marknode{Vslabel}
    \path (a) ++(\dx,0) coordinate(b);
    \marknode{b}
    \path ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
    \marknode{c}
  \end{circuitikz} \caption{Test circuit}
  \label{fig:test-circuit}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When run through LaTeX it looks just as I think it should:

[image]

But when viewed using Preview, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried wrapping the partway modifier in line 22 in braces {}.  The LaTeX output was unchanged, but running preview-at-point (C-c C-p C_p) produced this error in the Emacs minimbuffer:

[image]

along with a large number of Ghostscript errors (416 lines, which I am reluctant to inflict on readers here, but I will do so if that will help solve my problem.)

Additional edit:  entries from the preview log:

```
l.16 \begin{figure}
                   [h]
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgfutil@ifundefined ...@ifx \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \relax 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgfutil@ifundefined ...@ifx \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \relax 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);

./_region_.tex:27: Package pgf Error: No shape named `$(a' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...$(a}\csname pgf@sh@ma@$(a\endcsname 
                                                  \csname pgf@sh@np@$(a\endc...
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...ame \csname pgf@sh@np@$(a\endcsname 
                                                  \pgf@sh@reanchor {\csname ...
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgf@sh@ns@ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...hor@\csname pgf@sh@ns@$(a\endcsname 
                                                  @center
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgfutil@ifundefined ...@ifx \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \relax 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);

./_region_.tex:27: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `center' (in 'center').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgf@sh@ns@ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...hor@\csname pgf@sh@ns@$(a\endcsname 
                                                  @border\endcsname {\pgfqpo...
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no @ in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<argument> ...@ns@$(a\endcsname @border\endcsname 
                                                  {\pgfqpointpolar {\the \c@...
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgf@sh@ns@ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<argument> \csname pgf@sh@ns@$(a\endcsname 
                                           
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgf@sh@reanchor ...me pgf@anchor@#1@#2\endcsname 
                                                  }
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra }, or forgotten $.
\pgf@sh@reanchor ...e pgf@anchor@#1@#2\endcsname }
                                                  
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \endcsname 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \endcsname 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
<recently read> \endcsname 
                           
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgf@sh@pi@ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgf@marshal ...s@ \pgf@sh@pi@ \pr@$ (a\endcsname 
                                                  \endcsname 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgf@marshal ...pi@ \pr@$ (a\endcsname \endcsname 
                                                  
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...pointorigin \pgf@shape@original@pos 
                                                  
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Extra \endcsname.
\pgfutil@next ...@ns@\tikz@pp@name {#2}\endcsname 
                                                  \expandafter \ifx \csname ...
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pr@$ 
l.27     \path ($(a)
                    !0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);

./_region_.tex:27: Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.27     \path ($(a)!
                     0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
./_region_.tex:27: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.27     \path ($(a)!
                     0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 5 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
./_region_.tex:29: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.29   \end{circuitikz}
                        \caption{Test circuit}
Preview: Tightpage -32891 -32891 32891 32891
./_region_.tex:31: Preview: Snippet 1 ended.(11449270+0x22609920).
<-><->
      
l.31 \end{figure}
```

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{article}` to the above code snippet and change `\newcommand{\marknode}[1][45]{...` to `\newcommand{\marknode}[2][45]{...` I get the desired output with a current TeX Live distribution, no matter which compiler I use. Please explain in more detail what you do as I cannot really make sense of the errors you show. Make sure that both compilation processes use the same (and current) TeX distribution.

Comment: The \documentclass{article} was on the same line as the blockquotes marks, so was invisible.  I've fixed that.  I've put all the \usepackage macros on separate lines.  I corrected \newcommand{\marknode}[1][45] to \newcommand{\marknode}[2][45], which is how it actually appeared in my source code.  I don't know how it got changed to [1].   When I ran the file with LaTeX, I used this:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live
2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.21) 21 NOV 2023 16:28

I'm not sure where preview logs go, so it's hard for me to tell what compiler was used.

Comment: With the output you show on the second picture, you should actually also get some errors in the log. So it would be good to find these files. The log files are typically in the same directory like the PDF.

Comment: I think it's bundled with Auctex, which runs under Emacs.

Comment: I found the log for previews.  It's too long to appear in a comment, so I'll add it to the trail end of my original question.

Comment: It is probably enough to show the first error that is reported. And maybe the first line, to check the compiler. Is what you show really the *first* reported error?

Comment: The preview log includes this:  ```Running `Preview-LaTeX' on `/tmp/_region_' with ``pdflatex   -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error \&prv_test3 "/AUCTEXINPUT{" _region_.tex "}"''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make sense of this. The distribution is the same. Is this really the first error in the log? Are you sure the source files are the same? Maybe try compiling from scratch (meaning, deleting all aux files that might be there from the last compilation run).

Comment: I don't use emacs, so this is just a hint to find the problem. You are doing I suppose a preview on a region, and it seems to miss/miscontruct some command probably when building the preamble. Check if your region gets all the commands (eg, it does not start in the middle of a command); find a way to look at the `_region_.tex` file which is the one that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember that preview and tikz always had some issue due to handling of and/or expectation about `$`.  I think you have 2 choices:

1. Disable `textmath` for preview and get tikz figures, or
2. Source out your tikz figure into a file and include them back as graphics.

For 1., it looks like this in Emacs:
[image]

For 2, I made a new file `standalone-test.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\marknode}[2][45]{%
  \node[circle, draw, red, inner sep=1pt,
    pin={[red, font=\tiny]#1:#2}
  ] at (#2.center) {};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \def\dx{3} \def\dy{4} \draw (0,0) node[ground,name=gnd] {} (gnd)
  ++(0,\dy) coordinate(a) to[american voltage source,
    l_=$\begin{matrix} & + \\ & V_\textsc{s} \\ & \qty{10}{V} \\ & -
    \end{matrix}$,name=Vs] (gnd)
  (Vslabel) ++(-0.5,0) node[] {$I_\textsc{s} \big\uparrow$}
  ;
  \marknode{a} \marknode{Vslabel}
  \path (a) ++(\dx,0) coordinate(b);
  \marknode{b}
  \path ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) coordinate(c);
  \marknode{c}
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

And changed your .tex file to this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textmath,displaymath,footnotes,sections,floats]{preview}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Here we go with $a+b=c$.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[page=1]{standalone-test}
  \caption{Test circuit}
  \label{fig:test-circuit}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

which looks like this within Emacs and preview:
[image]